# C++ Text to Morse Code

Tags: c++, file, dynamic-arrays, morse-code

I was given a .txt file with the chars and the translation for them in morse code. I was told that I had to read the .txt file into two different arrays.

One array will contain the characters that are being mapped from and the second array will contain the equivalent Morse code.

this is what the .txt file contains.

39

,  --..--

. .-.-.-

?  ..--..

0 -----

1  .----

2  ..---

3  ...--

A  .-

and so on.

```
void readFile(string userMapping)
{

    fstream mappingFile;

    mappingFile.open(userMapping);

    if (mappingFile.is_open())
    {
        // call the next function
        cout << "Hello World!"; // ignore this, I was testing to see if the file was open.
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

How do I go about reading the file into two dynamically sized arrays from what they are asking here? 
"One array will contain the characters that are being mapped from and the second array will contain the equivalent Morse code."

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: There does not appear to be a question here.

Comment: In c++ when you read "dynamically sized array" think "std::vector" http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33631-c-vector-tutorial/

Comment: I wish I could use vectors on this, but our assignment sadly does not want this.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/ first array should be of `char` type, 2nd of `std::string` type... something like std::string * code = new std::string[256]; But then that's not dynamic... perhaps the first line in your file tells you the size (39) ?

Comment: Yea the file tells me the size is 39.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using the character as a subscript int into array where your code characters are.